# Disable default overscroll behaviour on ScrollView

Tags: java, android, javafx, javafx-8, javafxports

The JavaFX ScrollView has no default overscroll behaviour. But when you compile your app to Android (and iOS for what it's worth) using the javafxport project, the overscroll is suddenly possible.

I a special use case (when the scroll contains an image at the end of the scroll views content) this results on visible artifacts on the image that is currently scrolled).

I'd like to disable this functionality. Is there any easy way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit, 2019-11-08:**
Partial screenshot showing the artifacts I mentioned:
[image]

Comment: There is no built-in support for over scrolling on JavaFXPorts. By over scroll, do you mean the effect that you get in a JavaFX ScrollView on Android/iOS, when you scroll until the end, and you can still drag the content to the top?

Comment: Hi José. That effect is exactly what I mean. I took it for some kind of over scroll. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Can you tell me, if there is a way to disable it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi José. Just wanted to know, if there's something I can do. Is there a way to disable the overscroll on mobile? Or can you point me to the code, where this behaviour is implemented?  
I also added a screenshot to show, what I mean about artifacts.